# Tracking the flow of XML nodes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a `Process` table in SQL Server like this:

[image]

`workflowXML` column has values like this:

**Sample1:**

```
 <process>
      <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_1">
         <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0h5l5vu</outgoing>
      </Event>
      <Flow type="sequence"
            id="SequenceFlow_0h5l5vu"
            sourceRef="StartEvent_1"
            targetRef="Task_1qc93ha"/>
      <Flow type="sequence"
            id="SequenceFlow_120gi3p"
            sourceRef="Task_1qc93ha"
            targetRef="Task_0x1pjee"/>
      <Task type="service" id="Task_1qc93ha">
         <incoming>SequenceFlow_0h5l5vu</incoming>
         <outgoing>SequenceFlow_120gi3p</outgoing>
      </Task>
      <Task type="user" id="Task_0x1pjee">
         <incoming>SequenceFlow_120gi3p</incoming>
      </Task>
</process>
```

**Sample2:**

```
<process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">
      <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_142xowk">
         <outgoing>SequenceFlow_03yocm5</outgoing>
      </Event>
      <Flow type="sequence"
            id="SequenceFlow_03yocm5"
            sourceRef="StartEvent_142xowk"
            targetRef="Task_12g1q69"/>
      <Task type="user" id="Task_0x1pjee">
             <incoming>SequenceFlow_120gi3p</incoming>
       </Task>
      <Task type="user" id="Task_12g1q69">
         <incoming>SequenceFlow_03yocm5</incoming>
      </Task>
</process>
```

I want to track flow of nodes with `Flow` nodes. For example I need to query that return `Task` node that start from start event (`Event type="start"`) and finish in `Task` with user type (`type="user"`). This query in **Sample1** return `Task` node with `id="Task_0x1pjee"` and in **Sample2** return `Task` node with `id="Task_12g1q69"`.

I think this query has this structure:

[image: nodesflow]

**Edit1**

Sample3 has node so that they can have more than one incoming or outgoing.

```
  <process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">
    <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_1">
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0qn7l4p</outgoing>
    </Event>
    <Flow type="sequence" id="SequenceFlow_0qnhn9s" sourceRef="Task_1jfd878" targetRef="Task_15id5tl"/>
    <Task type="service" id="Task_1jfd878">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0qn7l4p</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0qnhn9s</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_10zjx6e</outgoing>
    </Task>
    <Flow type="sequence" id="SequenceFlow_0qn7l4p" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="Task_1jfd878"/>
    <Flow type="sequence" id="SequenceFlow_10zjx6e" sourceRef="Task_1jfd878" targetRef="Task_0qnuy6q"/>
    <Task type="user" id="Task_0qnuy6q">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_10zjx6e</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0xiah51</incoming>
    </Task>
    <Task type="service" id="Task_15id5tl">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0qnhn9s</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0xiah51</outgoing>
    </Task>
    <Flow type="sequence" id="SequenceFlow_0xiah51" sourceRef="Task_15id5tl" targetRef="Task_0qnuy6q"/>
  </process>
```

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this query.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want to store your data in proper tables instead of XML?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas No, I need store data in XML format.

Comment: Depending on the method used, XML already has methods to retrieve repeating nodes ( `'//<node>'`) or methods to return a specific duplicate node in a horizontal column( `'<node[2]>'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got this correctly:

You start with *type="start"* and walk down a hierarchy, where the *out*-data is the Id of the next node. This line has an undefined depth and should end at a node with *type="user"*.

Your second example has got 2 Tasks with *type="user"*, but only one of them is referenced as out-data in a higher node up the chain.

My example will filter the second with an extra `EXISTS` clause.

The first CTE *DerivedTable* consists of a query you might use isolated too. It will bring up the full information in table-wise format.

The second CTE is recursive, starts with the *start* and traverses down the chain. The column *Rank* is the chain's order.

The third CTE adds a reverse Rank as you seem to be interested in the last item only. You might get this by `WHERE RevRank=1`

```
DECLARE @process TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, workflowXML XML);
INSERT INTO @process(workflowXML) VALUES
('<process>
      <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_1">
         <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0h5l5vu</outgoing>
      </Event>
      <Flow type="sequence"
            id="SequenceFlow_0h5l5vu"
            sourceRef="StartEvent_1"
            targetRef="Task_1qc93ha"/>
      <Flow type="sequence"
            id="SequenceFlow_120gi3p"
            sourceRef="Task_1qc93ha"
            targetRef="Task_0x1pjee"/>
      <Task type="service" id="Task_1qc93ha">
         <incoming>SequenceFlow_0h5l5vu</incoming>
         <outgoing>SequenceFlow_120gi3p</outgoing>
      </Task>
      <Task type="user" id="Task_0x1pjee">
         <incoming>SequenceFlow_120gi3p</incoming>
      </Task>
</process>')
,('<process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">
      <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_142xowk">
         <outgoing>SequenceFlow_03yocm5</outgoing>
      </Event>
      <Flow type="sequence"
            id="SequenceFlow_03yocm5"
            sourceRef="StartEvent_142xowk"
            targetRef="Task_12g1q69"/>
      <Task type="user" id="Task_0x1pjee">
             <incoming>SequenceFlow_120gi3p</incoming>
       </Task>
      <Task type="user" id="Task_12g1q69">
         <incoming>SequenceFlow_03yocm5</incoming>
      </Task>
</process>');
```

--This is the query:

```
WITH DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT prTbl.ID AS tblID
          ,nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS [Name]
          ,nd.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS [Type]
          ,nd.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS Id
          ,COALESCE(nd.value('@sourceRef','nvarchar(max)')
                   ,nd.value('(incoming)[1]','nvarchar(max)')) AS [In]
          ,COALESCE(nd.value('@targetRef','nvarchar(max)')
                   ,nd.value('(outgoing)[1]','nvarchar(max)')) AS [Out]
    FROM @process AS prTbl
    CROSS APPLY prTbl.workflowXML.nodes('process') AS A(pr)
    CROSS APPLY pr.nodes('*') AS B(nd)
)
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT tblID,[Name],[Type],Id,[In],[Out],1 AS [Rank]
    FROM DerivedTable 
    WHERE [Type]='start'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT x.tblID,x.[Name],x.[Type],x.Id,x.[In],x.[Out],r.[Rank]+1
    FROM recCTE AS r
    INNER JOIN DerivedTable AS x ON x.[Id]=r.[Out] 
                                    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                                               FROM DerivedTable AS y 
                                               WHERE y.tblID=x.tblID AND y.[Out]=x.[Id])
)
,ReverseRank AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tblID ORDER BY [Rank] DESC) AS RevRank 
    FROM recCTE
)
SELECT * 
FROM ReverseRank
ORDER BY  tblID,[Rank]
```

The result (your expected output is at *RevRank=1*):

```
+-------+------+---------+-------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| tblID | Rank | RevRank | Name  | Type     | Id                   | In                   | Out                  |
+-------+------+---------+-------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 1     | 1    | 5       | Event | start    | StartEvent_1         | NULL                 | SequenceFlow_0h5l5vu |
+-------+------+---------+-------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 1     | 2    | 4       | Flow  | sequence | SequenceFlow_0h5l5vu | StartEvent_1         | Task_1qc93ha         |
+-------+------+---------+-------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 1     | 3    | 3       | Task  | service  | Task_1qc93ha         | SequenceFlow_0h5l5vu | SequenceFlow_120gi3p |
+-------+------+---------+-------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 1     | 4    | 2       | Flow  | sequence | SequenceFlow_120gi3p | Task_1qc93ha         | Task_0x1pjee         |
+-------+------+---------+-------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 1     | 5    | 1       | Task  | user     | Task_0x1pjee         | SequenceFlow_120gi3p | NULL                 |
+-------+------+---------+-------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 2     | 1    | 3       | Event | start    | StartEvent_142xowk   | NULL                 | SequenceFlow_03yocm5 |
+-------+------+---------+-------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 2     | 2    | 2       | Flow  | sequence | SequenceFlow_03yocm5 | StartEvent_142xowk   | Task_12g1q69         |
+-------+------+---------+-------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 2     | 3    | 1       | Task  | user     | Task_12g1q69         | SequenceFlow_03yocm5 | NULL                 |
+-------+------+---------+-------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

## UPDATE: Your comment

I tested my query with the XML from your comment:

```
INSERT INTO @process(workflowXML) VALUES
('<process>
  <Event type="start" id="e1">
    <outgoing>s1</outgoing>
  </Event>
  <Flow type="sequence" id="s1" sourceRef="e1" targetRef="t1" />
  <Flow type="sequence" id="s3" sourceRef="t1" targetRef="t2" />
  <Task type="user" id="t3">
    <incoming>s2</incoming>
  </Task>
  <Task type="user" id="t1">
    <incoming>s1</incoming>
    <outgoing>s3</outgoing>
  </Task>
  <Flow type="sequence" id="s2" sourceRef="t2" targetRef="t3" />
  <Task type="service" id="t2">
    <incoming>s3</incoming>
    <outgoing>s2</outgoing>
  </Task>
</process>');
```

This is the result

```
+-------+-------+----------+----+------+------+------+---------+
| tblID | Name  | Type     | Id | In   | Out  | Rank | RevRank |
+-------+-------+----------+----+------+------+------+---------+
| 1     | Event | start    | e1 | NULL | s1   | 1    | 7       |
+-------+-------+----------+----+------+------+------+---------+
| 1     | Flow  | sequence | s1 | e1   | t1   | 2    | 6       |
+-------+-------+----------+----+------+------+------+---------+
| 1     | Task  | user     | t1 | s1   | s3   | 3    | 5       |
+-------+-------+----------+----+------+------+------+---------+
| 1     | Flow  | sequence | s3 | t1   | t2   | 4    | 4       |
+-------+-------+----------+----+------+------+------+---------+
| 1     | Task  | service  | t2 | s3   | s2   | 5    | 3       |
+-------+-------+----------+----+------+------+------+---------+
| 1     | Flow  | sequence | s2 | t2   | t3   | 6    | 2       |
+-------+-------+----------+----+------+------+------+---------+
| 1     | Task  | user     | t3 | s2   | NULL | 7    | 1       |
+-------+-------+----------+----+------+------+------+---------+
```

If I understand the logic correctly my query works just fine:

- event id=e1 points to s1
- Flow s1 points to t1
- Task t1 points to s3
- Flow s3 points to t2
- Task t2 points to s2
- Flow s2 points to t3
- Task t3 is the end

The only thing which I see differently, is the fact, that *Task t1* was a *type="user"* already. If you want - in any case - the highest ranked user Task, you might take away the `ReverseRank`-CTE and set the final `SELECT` like

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM recCTE AS t
WHERE t.[Rank]<=ISNULL((SELECT MIN(x.[Rank]) FROM recCTE AS x WHERE x.tblID=t.tblID AND x.[Type]='user' AND x.[Name]='Task'),999)
ORDER BY t.tblID,t.[Rank]
```

Now *Task t1* will be the last result, as all later ranks are filtered out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, I posted a answer. Please see this.

Comment: @AliSoltani Did you try my approach? Your question - if it returns what you need - is okay, but is a *procedural* approach. With SQL it is always recommended to follow the *set-based* path... My query will return with the full chain of your flow and should be much faster than yours. The main problem with your approach is, that you pick one piece of data from your XML over and over, while mine is reading all at once. `CURSOR` and `WHILE`-loops is something one should avoid if possible... I'd suggest to try my approach and decide what is better for you...

Comment: I test your query. I think it is better. But one question. Sometimes, there are several incoming and outgoing in nodes. Is your code works properly in this case?

Comment: @AliSoltani Just try it out ... A recursive approach should work down a full tree. But I do not know your data

Comment: I've tested your query again with this query. Result is not correct.

Comment: <process>
  <Event type="start" id="e1">
    <outgoing>s1</outgoing>
  </Event>
  <Flow type="sequence" id="s1" sourceRef="e1" targetRef="t1"/>
  <Flow type="sequence" id="s3" sourceRef="t1" targetRef="t2"/>
  <Task type="user" id="t3">
    <incoming>s2</incoming>
  </Task>
  <Task type="user" id="t1">
    <incoming>s1</incoming>
    <outgoing>s3</outgoing>
  </Task>
  <Flow type="sequence" id="s2" sourceRef="t2" targetRef="t3"/>
  <Task type="service" id="t2">
    <incoming>s3</incoming>
    <outgoing>s2</outgoing>
  </Task>
</process>

Comment: Thanks for update query. I added sample for more than in or out please see this.

Comment: @AliSoltani just one more point to clarify: You example in comment was just a more complex tree, but the new example includes circles. A recursive approach must get additional logic to deal with this. This is something completely different then before. Therefore a *chameleon*

Comment: You are right,I accepted your answer and post new question.Of course I did not want ask chameleon question.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem with this query. If there is a better query, happy to point it out.

```
--================== @tempProcess(result)=========================
declare @tempProcess table 
(
 ID int,
 FirstTaskID nvarchar(max)
 )
--===============================================================
declare @currentType nvarchar(max)
declare @FirstUserTaskID nvarchar(max)
declare @outgoing nvarchar(max)
declare @elementID nvarchar(max)
--================================================================
declare @ID int
declare @WorkflowXML xml
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
    select ID, WorkflowXML from Process 
open cur

fetch next from cur into @ID, @WorkflowXML

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN    

set @currentType = '$$$$$'--defult value
set @elementID = '$$$$$'--defult value

select @outgoing = 
(
    select p.WorkflowXML.value('(process/Event[@type=''start'']/outgoing)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    from Process as p
    where ID = @ID
)

--======================  while(Tracking flow) ========================
while (@currentType != 'user')
begin
    ------- Get target element with Flow Id (outgoing)----------------- 
    select @elementID = (
        select t.c.value('@id','nvarchar(max)')
        from Process as p
            cross apply p.WorkflowXML.nodes('process/*') AS t(c)
        where ID = @ID
        and 
        t.c.value('incoming[1]','nvarchar(max)') = @outgoing
    )
    -------------- Get Type of current element ------------------------ 
    select @currentType = 
    (
    select t.c.value('@type','nvarchar(max)')
        from Process as p
            cross apply p.WorkflowXML.nodes('process/*') AS t(c)
        where ID = @ID
        and 
        t.c.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') = @elementID
    )
    -------------- Get outgoing of current element ---------------------    
    select @outgoing = 
    (
     select t.c.value('(outgoing)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
        from Process as p
            cross apply p.WorkflowXML.nodes('process/*') AS t(c)
        where ID = @ID
        and 
        t.c.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') = @elementID
    )
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
end
--=========================  End while ========================   
if(@elementID != '$$$$$')
    begin
        set @FirstUserTaskID =  @elementID      
        -- Insert to @tempProcess
        INSERT INTO @tempProcess
        SELECT @ID,@FirstUserTaskID
    end

    --select @FirstUserTaskID
    fetch next from cur into @ID,@WorkflowXML
END

select * from @tempProcess

close cur
deallocate cur
```