# Multiple goal search on XML nodes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, traversal

I have a Process table in SQL Server like this:

[image: workflow]

`workflowXML` column has values like this:

**sample1 (ProcessID=1)**

[image: sample1]

workflowXML of sample1:

```
<process>
    <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_1" name="Start">
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0z7u86p</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1onkt3z</outgoing>
    </Event>
    <task type="" id="Task_0a7vu1x" name="D">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_108ajnm</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1onkt3z</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_01clcmz</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="goal" id="Task_00ijt4n" name="B">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_17q1ecq</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0q9j3et</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1ygvv8b</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_02glv1g</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="" id="Task_1rnuz4y" name="A">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1ygvv8b</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0z7u86p</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_108ajnm</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_17q1ecq</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_075iuj9</outgoing>
    </task>                
    <task type="goal" id="Task_1d4ykor" name="E">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_01clcmz</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_075iuj9</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1djp3tu</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0q9j3et</outgoing>
    </task>        
    <task type="goal" id="Task_1sembw4" name="C">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_02glv1g</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1djp3tu</outgoing>
    </task>    
</process>
```

**sample2 (ProcessID=2)**

[image: sample2]

workflowXML of sample2:

```
<process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">
    <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_0bivq0x" name="Start">
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0q5ik20</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_147xk2x</outgoing>
    </Event>
    <task type="" id="Task_141buye" name="A">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0q5ik20</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0wg37hn</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1pvpyhe</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_10is4pe</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="" id="Task_1n3p00i" name="C">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_147xk2x</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_10is4pe</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_18ks1jr</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_08gxini</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="goal" id="Task_0olxqpp" name="B">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1pvpyhe</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_03eekq0</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="goal" id="Task_0zjgfkf" name="D">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_18ks1jr</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_03eekq0</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0wg37hn</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="" id="Task_1q71efy" name="E">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_08gxini</incoming>
    </task>
</process>
```

**Edit1 (Add Sample3)**

**sample3 (ProcessID=3)**

[image: Sample3]

workflowXML of sample3:

```
<process>
  <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_1" name="Start">
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_01rkkhj</outgoing>
  </Event>
  <task type="" id="Task_1jixk79" name="A">
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_01rkkhj</incoming>
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_1tszkq8</incoming>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0v8wuqu</outgoing>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_14u6fh7</outgoing>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1q4991g</outgoing>
  </task>
  <task type="" id="Task_0xwvhuo" name="B">
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_0v8wuqu</incoming>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_15fmkbq</outgoing>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0x4ykgp</outgoing>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0f4gpf1</outgoing>
  </task>
  <task type="goal" id="Task_0qsvlob" name="G">
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_0qse1xk</incoming>
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_16a0qvv</incoming>
  </task>
  <task type="goal" id="Task_0wtjftd" name="E">
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_14u6fh7</incoming>
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_0z3qle8</incoming>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0vg7sax</outgoing>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0qse1xk</outgoing>
  </task>
  <task type="" id="Task_0c85e6p" name="F">
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_0x4ykgp</incoming>
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_17k5zfg</incoming>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_16a0qvv</outgoing>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0z3qle8</outgoing>
  </task>
  <task type="" id="Task_164ihwt" name="D">
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_0q9hqs6</incoming>
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_1q4991g</incoming>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_17k5zfg</outgoing>
  </task>
  <task type="goal" id="Task_032o8jx" name="C">
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_15fmkbq</incoming>
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_0vg7sax</incoming>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0q9hqs6</outgoing>
    <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1tszkq8</outgoing>
  </task>
  <task type="goal" id="Task_0fsibap" name="H">
    <incoming>SequenceFlow_0f4gpf1</incoming>
  </task>
</process>
```

I need to find goal nodes from start node that:

there is a path for them from start and there are no goal nodes in this path.

Result of query in process table with `sample1` and `sample2` is like this:

```
+-------+----------+-------------+
|  ID   | nodeName |    nodeID   |
+-------+----------+-------------+
|   1   |    B     |Task_00ijt4n |
+-------+----------+-------------+
|   1   |    E     |Task_1d4ykor |
+-------+----------+-------------+
|   2   |    B     |Task_0olxqpp |
+-------+----------+-------------+
|   2   |    D     |Task_0zjgfkf |
+-------+----------+-------------+
```

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this query.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to get this clear: Other than your [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39053884/5089204) You have one single `Event` element which is the start and no other than `task` elements. In your last question there where `Flow` elements too? And - another very important difference - the element's id is not used anywhere. The full flow is built up by `incoming` and `outgoing` elements. Is this correct?

Comment: @Shnugo I have one single `Event` element, `Flows` removed from XML (We do not need them), I added id column in result, finally yes this is correct.

Comment: This is really difficult to solve... This is kind of *route planning* or *travelling salesman dilemma*. There are dead ends and circles... At the moment I do not have enough time to dive into it and I doubt, that T-SQL is the best tool for that. I'll get back later... Maybe someone else has a greate idea

Comment: Anyway I think that this is one of the rare moments where a `WHILE` loop or a `CURSOR` might be the right choice...

Comment: @Shnugo I think this is kind of breadth-first traversal. Travelling salesman is NP-Hard problem that each node can be started but in this case I have one start node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious to solve this with a set-based recursive approach as I do not like procedural coding in T-SQL. Hope you like it :-)

```
DECLARE @process TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, workflowXML XML);
INSERT INTO @process(workflowXML) VALUES
('<process>
    <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_1" name="Start">
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0z7u86p</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1onkt3z</outgoing>
    </Event>
    <task type="" id="Task_0a7vu1x" name="D">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_108ajnm</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1onkt3z</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_01clcmz</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="goal" id="Task_00ijt4n" name="B">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_17q1ecq</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0q9j3et</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1ygvv8b</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_02glv1g</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="" id="Task_1rnuz4y" name="A">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1ygvv8b</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0z7u86p</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_108ajnm</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_17q1ecq</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_075iuj9</outgoing>
    </task>                
    <task type="goal" id="Task_1d4ykor" name="E">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_01clcmz</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_075iuj9</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1djp3tu</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0q9j3et</outgoing>
    </task>        
    <task type="goal" id="Task_1sembw4" name="C">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_02glv1g</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1djp3tu</outgoing>
    </task>    
</process>')
,('<process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">
    <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_0bivq0x" name="Start">
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0q5ik20</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_147xk2x</outgoing>
    </Event>
    <task type="" id="Task_141buye" name="A">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0q5ik20</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0wg37hn</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1pvpyhe</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_10is4pe</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="" id="Task_1n3p00i" name="C">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_147xk2x</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_10is4pe</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_18ks1jr</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_08gxini</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="goal" id="Task_0olxqpp" name="B">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1pvpyhe</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_03eekq0</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="goal" id="Task_0zjgfkf" name="D">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_18ks1jr</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_03eekq0</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0wg37hn</outgoing>
    </task>
    <task type="" id="Task_1q71efy" name="E">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_08gxini</incoming>
    </task>
</process>');
```

--the query

```
WITH DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT prTbl.ID AS tblID
          ,nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
          ,nd.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS [Type]
          ,nd.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS Id
          ,nd.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS [Name]
          ,nd.query('.') AS Task
    FROM @process AS prTbl
    CROSS APPLY prTbl.workflowXML.nodes('process') AS A(pr)
    CROSS APPLY pr.nodes('*') AS B(nd)
)
,AllIncoming AS
(
    SELECT tblId
          ,NodeName 
          ,[Type]
          ,Id 
          ,[Name]
          ,i.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS [Target] 
    FROM DerivedTable
    CROSS APPLY Task.nodes('task/incoming') AS A(i)
    WHERE NodeName='task'
)
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT tblID,NodeName,[Type],Id,[Name],Task,1 AS Step,' | ' +CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS NodePath
    FROM DerivedTable 
    WHERE [Type]='start'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT nxt.tblID,nxt.NodeName,nxt.[Type],nxt.Id,nxt.[Name],nxt.Task,r.Step+1,r.NodePath + ' | ' + nxt.Id
    FROM recCTE AS r
    INNER JOIN DerivedTable AS nxt ON nxt.Id IN(SELECT x.Id 
                                                FROM AllIncoming AS x 
                                                WHERE x.[Target] IN (SELECT o.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                                                                     FROM r.Task.nodes('*/outgoing') AS A(o)
                                                                    )
                                                )
    WHERE r.[Type]<>'goal' 
      AND r.NodePath NOT LIKE '%| ' + nxt.Id + '%' 
      AND r.Step<=10 --add an appropriate depth limit to avoid recusion-depth error
)
SELECT t.tblID 
      ,t.[Name] 
      ,t.NodePath
      ,t.Step
      ,t.Id
FROM recCTE AS t
WHERE t.[Type]='goal'
  AND t.Step<=ISNULL((SELECT MIN(x.Step) FROM recCTE AS x WHERE x.tblID=t.tblID AND x.[Type]='goal' AND x.NodeName='task'),999)
ORDER BY t.tblID,t.Step
```

The result

```
tblID   Name    NodePath                                          Step  Id
  1     B      | StartEvent_1 | Task_1rnuz4y | Task_00ijt4n        3    Task_00ijt4n
  1     E      | StartEvent_1 | Task_1rnuz4y | Task_1d4ykor        3    Task_1d4ykor
  1     E      | StartEvent_1 | Task_0a7vu1x | Task_1d4ykor        3    Task_1d4ykor
  2     D      | StartEvent_0bivq0x | Task_1n3p00i | Task_0zjgfkf  3    Task_0zjgfkf
  2     B      | StartEvent_0bivq0x | Task_141buye | Task_0olxqpp  3    Task_0olxqpp
```

You find more than two results for tblID=1 as there are differing paths leading to the same goal node.

### UPDATE Your example 3

My first attempt finds the shortest path to a goal. Any goal, which is reached with a longer path, was filtered. This is easy to change:

Let the final `WHERE` find the shortest path to a specific node by adding the Id:

```
WHERE t.[Type]='goal'
  AND t.Step<=ISNULL((SELECT MIN(x.Step) 
                      FROM recCTE AS x 
                      WHERE x.tblID=t.tblID
                        AND x.Id=t.Id 
                        AND x.[Type]='goal' AND x.NodeName='task'),999)
```

This returns for all three examples:

```
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| tblID | Name | NodePath                                                                   | Step | Id           |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| 1     | B    | | StartEvent_1 | Task_1rnuz4y | Task_00ijt4n                               | 3    | Task_00ijt4n |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| 1     | E    | | StartEvent_1 | Task_1rnuz4y | Task_1d4ykor                               | 3    | Task_1d4ykor |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| 1     | E    | | StartEvent_1 | Task_0a7vu1x | Task_1d4ykor                               | 3    | Task_1d4ykor |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| 2     | B    | | StartEvent_0bivq0x | Task_141buye | Task_0olxqpp                         | 3    | Task_0olxqpp |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| 2     | D    | | StartEvent_0bivq0x | Task_1n3p00i | Task_0zjgfkf                         | 3    | Task_0zjgfkf |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| 3     | E    | | StartEvent_1 | Task_1jixk79 | Task_0wtjftd                               | 3    | Task_0wtjftd |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| 3     | C    | | StartEvent_1 | Task_1jixk79 | Task_0xwvhuo | Task_032o8jx                | 4    | Task_032o8jx |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| 3     | H    | | StartEvent_1 | Task_1jixk79 | Task_0xwvhuo | Task_0fsibap                | 4    | Task_0fsibap |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| 3     | G    | | StartEvent_1 | Task_1jixk79 | Task_0xwvhuo | Task_0c85e6p | Task_0qsvlob | 5    | Task_0qsvlob |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| 3     | G    | | StartEvent_1 | Task_1jixk79 | Task_164ihwt | Task_0c85e6p | Task_0qsvlob | 5    | Task_0qsvlob |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
```

Comment: The problem with applying set based approach to graph theory problems is that the algorithm will explode first the solution space to all possible combinations and then filter out the ones that do not match the requirement. This works fine for small sets, but runs out of resources on larger graphs. Still, and impressive answer :)

Comment: @RemusRusanu, thx :-) I know about recursive explosions...  But I've had an idea: I added `AND r.NodePath NOT LIKE '%| ' + nxt.Id + '%' ` which breaks, if i re-visit a node - voila!

Comment: Procedural thinking in a declarative environment :) The optimizer will punish you, one way or another. Some day it'll be changing  *some* order of execution, somewhere in the execution tree, and *bam!* the filter is applied higher on the stack. I once invested some +2 months into similar problem with `RECEIVE` statement implementation only to end up being told by the optimizer team to f*** off, [they do not make any order guarantees](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=170078) :)

Comment: @RemusRusanu, yes, this is something one should consider... I'd really love something like a `TREAT_AS_TABLE` keyword in combination with a `CTE`. I'm pretty sure, if you would use declared (in-memory) table variables or even indexed temp tables instead of the CTEs, the order of the execution would not make much difference. CTEs are greate but really dangerous in this point of view...

Comment: Hi @RemusRusanu, your linked article is from 1993 :-) I once encountered a situation where a very expensive scalar operation which should have been performed only once per row on a very small set was performed on each row of the very large set *after* several joins. Using a table variable instead of the CTE reduced the query time incredibly...

Comment: @RemusRusanu ... and one more thought: As far as I know the recursive CTE is handled as *hidden RBAR*  anyhow... Therefore I would not expect **this** predicat to be shifted somewhere else... But one never knows...

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. I tested you query with sample 3 but result is E. This is not correct.

Comment: @AliSoltani, Your Start links to A and A links to E which is a goal. If the result is E this should be fine, shouldn't it? Cannot Test it at the moment. What is the result?

Comment: @AliSoltani I think I understand now... See my update

Comment: I post new question like this. I am grateful to see new question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425642/add-where-condition-for-check-attribute-value-in-xml-nodes)