# Add where condition for check attribute value in XML nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have this SQL query:

```
DECLARE @process TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, workflowXML XML, Name nvarchar(250),Description nvarchar(MAX));
INSERT INTO @process(workflowXML,Name,Description) VALUES
('<process>
    <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_1">
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1uj46ib</outgoing>
    </Event>
    <Task type="service" id="Task_0uurv2v">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1uj46ib</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_051szgj</outgoing>
    </Task>
    <Task type="user" id="Task_1yh7nak">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_051szgj</incoming>
      <TaskUsers>
        <TaskUser RoleName="myFirstRole" />
        <TaskUser RoleName="mySecondRole" />
      </TaskUsers>      
    </Task>
  </process>'
  ,'Process1'
  ,'test Process 1')
,('<process>
    <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_1" name="Start">
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0z7u86p</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1onkt3z</outgoing>
    </Event>
    <Task type="service" id="Task_0a7vu1x">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_108ajnm</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1onkt3z</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_01clcmz</outgoing>
    </Task>
    <Task type="user" id="Task_00ijt4n">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_17q1ecq</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0q9j3et</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1ygvv8b</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_02glv1g</outgoing>
    </Task>
    <Task type="service" id="Task_1rnuz4y">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1ygvv8b</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0z7u86p</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_108ajnm</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_17q1ecq</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_075iuj9</outgoing>
    </Task>                
    <Task type="user" id="Task_1d4ykor">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_01clcmz</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_075iuj9</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1djp3tu</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0q9j3et</outgoing>
      <TaskUsers>
        <TaskUser RoleName="myFirstRole" />
        <TaskUser RoleName="mySecondRole" />
      </TaskUsers> 
    </Task>        
    <Task type="user" id="Task_1sembw4">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_02glv1g</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1djp3tu</outgoing>
      <TaskUsers>
        <TaskUser RoleName="myFirstRole" />
        <TaskUser RoleName="mySecondRole" />
      </TaskUsers> 
    </Task>    
</process>'
  ,'Process2'
  ,'test Process 2')
,('<process>
    <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_0bivq0x">
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0q5ik20</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_147xk2x</outgoing>
    </Event>
    <Task type="service" id="Task_141buye">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0q5ik20</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_0wg37hn</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_1pvpyhe</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_10is4pe</outgoing>
    </Task>
    <Task type="service" id="Task_1n3p00i" >
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_147xk2x</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_10is4pe</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_18ks1jr</outgoing>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_08gxini</outgoing>
    </Task>
    <Task type="user" id="Task_0olxqpp">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_1pvpyhe</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_03eekq0</outgoing>
    </Task>
    <Task type="user" id="Task_0zjgfkf">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_18ks1jr</incoming>
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_03eekq0</incoming>
      <outgoing>SequenceFlow_0wg37hn</outgoing>
      <TaskUsers>
            <TaskUser RoleName="mythirdRole" />
      </TaskUsers>
    </Task>
    <Task type="service" id="Task_1q71efy">
      <incoming>SequenceFlow_08gxini</incoming>
    </Task>
</process>'
  ,'Process3'
  ,'test Process 3')
;

WITH DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT prTbl.ID AS tblID
          ,nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
          ,nd.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS [Type]
          ,nd.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS Id
          ,nd.query('.') AS Task
          ,prTbl.Name AS [Name]
          ,prTbl.Description AS [Description]
    FROM @process AS prTbl
    CROSS APPLY prTbl.workflowXML.nodes('process') AS A(pr)
    CROSS APPLY pr.nodes('*') AS B(nd)
)
,AllIncoming AS
(
    SELECT tblId
          ,NodeName 
          ,[Type]
          ,Id 
          ,[Name]
          ,[Description]
          ,i.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS [Target] 
    FROM DerivedTable
    CROSS APPLY Task.nodes('Task/incoming') AS A(i)

    WHERE NodeName='Task'
)
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT tblID,NodeName,[Type],Id,[Name],[Description],Task,1 AS Step,' | ' +CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS NodePath
    FROM DerivedTable 
    WHERE [Type]='start'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT nxt.tblID,nxt.NodeName,nxt.[Type],nxt.Id,nxt.[Name],nxt.Description,nxt.Task,r.Step+1,r.NodePath + ' | ' + nxt.Id
    FROM recCTE AS r
    INNER JOIN DerivedTable AS nxt ON nxt.Id IN(SELECT x.Id 
                                                FROM AllIncoming AS x 
                                                WHERE x.[Target] IN (SELECT o.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                                                                     FROM r.Task.nodes('*/outgoing') AS A(o)
                                                                    )
                                                )
    WHERE r.[Type]<>'user' 
      AND r.NodePath NOT LIKE '%| ' + nxt.Id + '%' 
      AND r.Step<=10 
)
select a.tblID as ProcessID,[Name],[Description],a.NodePath,a.Id as TaskID
from
(
    SELECT t.tblID 
      ,t.[Name] 
      ,t.Description
      ,t.NodePath
      ,t.Id
    FROM recCTE AS t
    WHERE t.[Type]='user'
        AND t.Step<=ISNULL((SELECT MIN(x.Step) FROM recCTE AS x WHERE x.tblID=t.tblID AND x.[Type]='user' AND x.NodeName='Task'),10000)  
) a
ORDER BY a.tblID
```

This returns `Task` nodes that are first node can be seen from start event (`Event type="start"`). `NodePath` explains path from start event to target node.
Result of this query is like this:

[image: result1]

I need to new query that select from result where `RoleName`

```
<TaskUsers>
   <TaskUser RoleName="myFirstRole" />
   <TaskUser RoleName="mySecondRole" />
</TaskUsers>
```

exists in output of `SplitbyDelimiter` function.

`SplitbyDelimiter` function splits a string by `,`. For example:

```
 select * from SplitbyDelimiter('myFirstRole,mySecondRole',',')
```

returns

[image: split]

I edited `DerivedTable` part like this:

```
WITH DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT prTbl.ID AS tblID
          ,nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
          ,nd.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS [Type]
          ,nd.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS Id
          ,nd.query('.') AS Task
          ,prTbl.Name AS [Name]
          ,prTbl.Description AS [Description]
          --,t.c.value('@RoleName','nvarchar(max)') as [Role]
    FROM @process AS prTbl
    CROSS APPLY prTbl.workflowXML.nodes('process') AS A(pr)
    CROSS APPLY pr.nodes('*') AS B(nd)
    CROSS APPLY prTbl.workflowXML.nodes('process/Task/TaskUsers/TaskUser') AS t(c)
    where t.c.value('@RoleName','nvarchar(max)') in (select * from SplitbyDelimiter('myFirstRole,mySecondRole',','))
)
```

But It is not correct and return 216 records!(reason:Existence extra columns with different values).Also I added `inner join result` in end of query but this is not working fine.

**Update**

I used this query:

```
WITH DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT prTbl.ID AS tblID
          ,nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
          ,nd.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS [Type]
          ,nd.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS Id
          ,nd.query('.') AS Task
          ,prTbl.Name AS [Name]
          ,prTbl.Description AS [Description]
          ,t.c.value('@RoleName','nvarchar(max)') as [Role]
    FROM @process AS prTbl
    CROSS APPLY prTbl.workflowXML.nodes('process') AS A(pr)
    CROSS APPLY pr.nodes('*') AS B(nd)
    CROSS APPLY prTbl.workflowXML.nodes('process/Task/TaskUsers/TaskUser') AS t(c)      
)
,AllIncoming AS
(
    SELECT tblId
          ,NodeName 
          ,[Type]
          ,Id 
          ,[Name]
          ,[Description]
          ,i.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS [Target] 
    FROM DerivedTable
    CROSS APPLY Task.nodes('Task/incoming') AS A(i)

    WHERE NodeName='Task'
)
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT tblID,NodeName,[Type],Id,[Name],[Description],[Role],Task,1 AS Step,' | ' +CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS NodePath
    FROM DerivedTable 
    WHERE [Type]='start'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT nxt.tblID,nxt.NodeName,nxt.[Type],nxt.Id,nxt.[Name],nxt.Description,nxt.Role,nxt.Task,r.Step+1,r.NodePath + ' | ' + nxt.Id
    FROM recCTE AS r
    INNER JOIN DerivedTable AS nxt ON nxt.Id IN(SELECT x.Id 
                                                FROM AllIncoming AS x 
                                                WHERE x.[Target] IN (SELECT o.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                                                                     FROM r.Task.nodes('*/outgoing') AS A(o)
                                                                    )
                                                )
    WHERE r.[Type]<>'user' 
      AND r.NodePath NOT LIKE '%| ' + nxt.Id + '%' 
      AND r.Step<=10 
)
select a.tblID as ProcessID,[Name],[Description],a.NodePath,a.Id as TaskID,count(*) as records
from
(
    SELECT t.tblID 
      ,t.[Name] 
      ,t.Description
      ,t.NodePath
      ,t.Id
      ,t.Role     

    FROM recCTE AS t
    WHERE t.[Type]='user'
        AND t.Step<=ISNULL((SELECT MIN(x.Step) FROM recCTE AS x WHERE x.tblID=t.tblID AND x.[Type]='user' AND x.NodeName='Task'),10000)  
) a

INNER JOIN  [dbo].[SplitbyDelimiter]('myFirstRole,mySecondRole',',') r 
    ON r.TheField = a.Role
    group by a.tblID,[Name],[Description],a.NodePath,a.Id
    ORDER BY a.tblID
```

This returns:
 [image: result2]

This query return too many same records and run time for it is `19s`!!. It is not good query.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this query.

Comment: Wrong language (tool) for the job, and I would hate to be the next engineer who has to maintain that code. SQL is a data persistence tool not an XML tool. Use a procedural language with a quality XML parser and query language, e.g. C# with LINQ etc.

Comment: @TFD Real data have Large volumes and stored in a SQL Server database. For this reason,I need to this query.

Comment: Run the service on the same server/network. Either way the SQL IO's are going to happen, it's just a matter of how hard it is to understand what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query

> I used this query:
>
> ```
> WITH DerivedTable AS
> (
>     SELECT prTbl.ID AS tblID
>           ,nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
>           ,nd.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS [Type]
>           ,nd.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS Id
>           ,nd.query('.') AS Task
>           ,prTbl.Name AS [Name]
>           ,prTbl.Description AS [Description]
>           ,t.c.value('@RoleName','nvarchar(max)') as [Role]
>     FROM @process AS prTbl
>     CROSS APPLY prTbl.workflowXML.nodes('process') AS A(pr)
>     CROSS APPLY pr.nodes('*') AS B(nd)
>     CROSS APPLY prTbl.workflowXML.nodes('process/Task/TaskUsers/TaskUser') AS t(c)    
>
> )
> ```

uses the wrong path in the last `CROSS APPLY`. You'll get **all TaksUser elements**. Hence the many rows... You might change this to

```
[...]
CROSS APPLY pr.nodes('*') AS B(nd)
OUTER APPLY nd.nodes('TaskUsers/TaskUser') AS t(c)
```

to collect all TaskUser-elements below the current node...

### But:

The whole approach to work down your WorkFlow would break, if you add rows to the original resultset!

### What you can try:

Add the information **as additional column** and let the rest untouched. In my query I do this twice (TaskUsers and RoleNames), as I do not really understand, what you want to do with this:

```
WITH DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT prTbl.ID AS tblID
          ,nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
          ,nd.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS [Type]
          ,nd.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS Id
          ,nd.query('.') AS Task
          ,prTbl.Name AS [Name]
          ,prTbl.Description AS [Description]
          ,nd.query('./TaskUsers/TaskUser') AS TaskUsers
          ,nd.query('./TaskUsers/TaskUser').query('for $rn in /TaskUser return string($rn/@RoleName)').value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS RoleNames
    FROM @process AS prTbl
    CROSS APPLY prTbl.workflowXML.nodes('process') AS A(pr)
    CROSS APPLY pr.nodes('*') AS B(nd)
)
,AllIncoming AS
(
    SELECT tblId
          ,NodeName 
          ,[Type]
          ,Id 
          ,[Name]
          ,[Description]
          ,TaskUsers
          ,RoleNames
          ,i.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS [Target] 
    FROM DerivedTable
    CROSS APPLY Task.nodes('Task/incoming') AS A(i)

    WHERE NodeName='Task'
)
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT tblID,NodeName,[Type],Id,[Name],[Description],TaskUsers,RoleNames,Task,1 AS Step,' | ' +CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS NodePath
    FROM DerivedTable 
    WHERE [Type]='start'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT nxt.tblID,nxt.NodeName,nxt.[Type],nxt.Id,nxt.[Name],nxt.Description,nxt.TaskUsers,nxt.RoleNames,nxt.Task,r.Step+1,r.NodePath + ' | ' + nxt.Id
    FROM recCTE AS r
    INNER JOIN DerivedTable AS nxt ON nxt.Id IN(SELECT x.Id 
                                                FROM AllIncoming AS x 
                                                WHERE x.[Target] IN (SELECT o.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                                                                     FROM r.Task.nodes('*/outgoing') AS A(o)
                                                                    )
                                                )
    WHERE r.[Type]<>'user' 
      AND r.NodePath NOT LIKE '%| ' + nxt.Id + '%' 
      AND r.Step<=10 
)
select a.tblID as ProcessID,[Name],[Description],TaskUsers,RoleNames,a.NodePath,a.Id as TaskID
from
(
    SELECT t.tblID 
      ,t.[Name] 
      ,t.Description
      ,t.TaskUsers
      ,t.RoleNames
      ,t.NodePath
      ,t.Id
    FROM recCTE AS t
    WHERE t.[Type]='user'
        AND t.Step<=ISNULL((SELECT MIN(x.Step) FROM recCTE AS x WHERE x.tblID=t.tblID AND x.[Type]='user' AND x.NodeName='Task'),10000)  
) a
ORDER BY a.tblID
```

The result looks like this

[image]

What ever you want to do with this additional information, any filter you want to apply, should be done as the last step...

But - to be honest - you've reached the limits of SQL-Server... This is not the right tool. Sooner or later there will be some more business logic to implement... If this has to be done within SQL Server you might think of a CLR-method...

Comment: Your descriptions are very good. I am a university teacher who had many students. But I feel happy because I am your student :-).