# How to Get the Shorthest Path in a Flightroutes-Table

Tags: sql, oracle, shortest-path

I have trouble in getting a statement to get all stopovers on a flight.

I have table with flightroutes as below, which has a source-airport and a destination-airport.
Now i want to get the shortest flightroutes (the least stopovers) from Airport A to Airport B, there is no direct route from A to B so i have to connect several routes together.

So for example, if i want to go from 18 to 1403  i want to get the routes

```
(18 > 24 | 24 > 87 | 87 > 1403)
```

and not

```
(18 > 24 | 24 > 87 | 87 > 99| 99 > 1403)
```

Here is some test data

```
src_apid | dst_apid
---------+----------
18       | 24
24       | 87
87       | 99
87       | 1403
99       | 18
99       | 1403
```

My try looks like this:

```
WITH rejkabrest (
src_apid,
dst_apid
) AS (
SELECT
    src_apid,
    dst_apid
FROM
    routes
WHERE
    src_apid = 18  
UNION ALL 
SELECT
    a.src_apid,
    a.dst_apid
FROM
    routes a
    INNER JOIN rejkabrest b ON a.src_apid = b.dst_apid
    WHERE b.dst_apid = 1403
) SELECT
src_apid, dst_apid
FROM
rejkabrest;
```

But this way i only get all routes which start at source-airport 18. And if i try another way, i get a loop-problem.

Hope you guys can help me. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39119303/5089204) is SQL-Server syntax, but might point you the way. The main trick is, to carry a growing string with all visited stations and stop the recursion if one place is re-visited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `connect by nocycle` and function `rank()`:

```
select path
  from (
    select r.*, rank() over (order by lvl) rnk
      from (select routes.*, level lvl, 
                   sys_connect_by_path(src_apid, '->')||'->'||dst_apid path
              from routes 
              connect by nocycle src_apid = prior dst_apid and src_apid <> 1403
              start with src_apid = 18) r
      where dst_apid = 1403 )
  where rnk = 1
```

Demo:

```
with routes (src_apid, dst_apid ) as (
    select 18,   24 from dual union all
    select 24,   87 from dual union all
    select 87,   99 from dual union all
    select 87, 1403 from dual union all
    select 99,   18 from dual union all
    select 99, 1403 from dual )
select path
  from (
    select r.*, rank() over (order by lvl) rnk
      from (select routes.*, level lvl, 
                   sys_connect_by_path(src_apid, '->')||'->'||dst_apid path
              from routes 
              connect by nocycle src_apid = prior dst_apid and src_apid <> 1403
              start with src_apid = 18) r
      where dst_apid = 1403 )
  where rnk = 1

PATH
--------------------
->18->24->87->1403
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to build the path recursively. Use the `CYCLE` clause to avoid cycle exceptions. You get the shortest path from the found paths with Oracle's `KEEP FIRST`.

```
with cte (dst_apid, path, stops) as
(
  select dst_apid, src_apid || ' > ' || dst_apid as path, 0 as stops
  from routes
  where src_apid = 18  
  union all 
  select r.dst_apid, cte.path || ' > ' || r.dst_apid, cte.stops + 1
  from cte 
  join routes r on r.src_apid = cte.dst_apid
  where cte.dst_apid <> 1403
)
cycle dst_apid set cycle to 1 default 0
select max(path) keep (dense_rank first order by stops)
from cte
where cte.dst_apid = 1403;
```

Apart from `KEEP FIRST` this is standard SQL. You could use `SELECT path FROM cte WHERE dst_apid = 1403 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` instead to make this standard compliant. Oracle supports this syntax as of 12c.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. You might want to change stops to cte.stops in line 7 for future readers (otherwise it won't work, at least for me). I wasn't really able to execute the query since my table has thousands of rows. Would it be possible to add a maximum number of for stops between the flights to increase performance? After waiting for 30 minutes I still didn't get  any result :-/

Comment: Well, it works for me without the qualifier, but I'll add it, as this obviously depends on the Oracle version then (or you have a column named stops in the routes table). Of course you can limit the number of stops, e.g.: where `cte.dst_apid <> 1403 and cte.stops < 4` in the cte. (`cte.stops < 4` limits to 4 stops; use whatever number you want.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a row per flight, the only solution that comes to mind is two recursive queries. The first builds the flight routes with numbers 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.1.1, etc.; the seconds collects the flights that belong to the same route. Rather complicated:

```
with cte1 (routepart, pos, src_apid, dst_apid) as
(
    select to_char(rownum) as routepart, 1 as pos, src_apid, dst_apid
    from routes
    where src_apid = 18  
  union all 
  select cte1.routepart || '-' || rownum, pos + 1, r.src_apid, r.dst_apid
  from cte1 
  join routes r on r.src_apid = cte1.dst_apid
  where cte1.dst_apid <> 1403
)
cycle src_apid set cycle to 1 default 0
, cte2 (route, routepart, pos, src_apid, dst_apid) as
(
  select routepart as route, routepart, pos, src_apid, dst_apid
  from cte1
  where dst_apid = 1403
  union all
  select cte2.route, cte1.routepart, cte1.pos, cte1.src_apid, cte1.dst_apid
  from cte1
  join cte2 on cte2.routepart like cte1.routepart || '%'
            and nvl(length(regexp_replace(cte2.routepart, '[[:digit:]]', '')), 0) =
                nvl(length(regexp_replace(cte1.routepart, '[[:digit:]]', '')), 0) + 1
)
cycle src_apid set cycle to 1 default 0
select pos, src_apid, dst_apid
from
(
  select
    cte2.*, 
    rank() over (order by length(regexp_replace(route, '[[:digit:]]', ''))) as rn
  from cte2
)
where rn = 1
order by route, pos;
```

Use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK` if you don't want ties.